# Probability question related to independent/dependent event and conditional probability

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

An investment company estimates that the probability that stocks a and b go up is 61 % and 75%,
respectively. Let A be the event that stock a goes up, and let B be the event that stock b goes up.
Assume for simplicity that a stock can only go up or go down (i.e. ignore the case where the stock
maintains exactly the same value).

(a) Assuming that the events A and B are independent, compute the probability that both
stocks go up.

(b) Show that the probability that both stocks go up cannot be smaller than 36%, no matter
whether events A and B are independent or not.

(c) Suppose that it is impossible for both stocks to go down. Compute the probability that
both stocks go up.

So I am dealing with question of probability, I manage to figure the a) and b) sub question by understand  the meaning of dependent event and independent event but I am kind of the stuck in the third sub question c)

a) is simply multiply 61% and 75% together

b) is the probability the stock a goes up multiply the probability the stock b goes up given that stock a goes up

How about c)?
I am guessing that I need to use conditional probability with the statement (impossible for both stock to go down) but I have no idea how to translate the statement in to math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both $(b)$ and $(c)$ parts, use the inclusion-exlcusion principle:$$P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\text{ or }B)$$For $(b)$, note that $P(A\text{ or }B)\le1$ so $P(A\text{ and }B)\ge P(A)+P(B)-1=0.36$.

For $(c)$ you are given $P(A'\text{ and }B')=0\implies P(A\text{ or }B)=1-P(A'\text{ and }B')=1$ giving $P(A\text{ and }B)=0.36$.

Comment: Can you explain more on why P(A or B) less then  or equal 1?

Comment: @Antonymous It is a probability no

Comment: Also why can't calculate the dependent event with P(A goes up) * P(B goes up | A goes up)

Comment: @Antonymous Has $P(B|A)$ been given to u?

Comment: First what do you mean probability no? second, the question does not provide me P(B|A) but form my understanding of dependent event, does P(A) * P(B|A)  make sense?

Comment: Yes $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\times P(B|A)$. Since $P(A\text{ or }B)$ is a probability it will be $\le1$

Comment: I start to understand what are you talking about, I can't calculate P(B|A) = P(A and B) / p(A) using a answer?right?

Comment: Yes, you can't find $P(B|A)$ using part $(a)$ because it is a special case where events are independent. When events are dependent $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ not necessarily true. @Antonymous